# Set Timezone For User Before Create Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, timezone

I am attempting to implement correct time zone handling in Rails.

Every user has a different time zone, so each user's time zone exists in the database.

The problem: when I create a user, I pass onto the time zone what I get from the client.

The user have some fields like created, but I want to save the correct time when I create the user and *not* when I update the model.

This is my model:

```
require 'securerandom'

class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paperclip

  field :created, type: Time
  field :time_zone, type: String

  def set_created
    self.created = Time.now.in_time_zone(self.time_zone)
  end
end
```

This is the Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods
    around_filter :set_time_zone


  def current_user
    return unless params[:user_id]
    @current_user ||= User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  private

  def set_time_zone(&block)
    time_zone = current_user.try(:time_zone) || 'UTC'
    Time.use_zone(time_zone, &block)
  end       
end
```

I set `around_filter` yet I don't know how to pass the `time_zone` parameters into it. `Currentuser` doesn't work because the user is not created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html), please reference the Ruby on Rails guide on Callbacks [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html).

In this case, you want to run your function *only* when the record is created, so you will use `before_create`:

```
class User
  before_create :set_created

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paperclip

  field :created, type: Time
  field :time_zone, type: String

  def set_created
    self.created = Time.now.in_time_zone(self.time_zone)
  end
end
```

Please note the before_create at the top of the class.

Comment: nope don't work and before_create at the top of the class is wrong :(